# Flann vs. Brute Force matcher

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, gpu

Lately I've been reading about CUDA, feature detection, Flann based matcher, Brute force matcher etc. I've recently developed a demo with GPU Brute Force matcher and the computation is pretty fast. I've also read that the Flann based matcher is much much faster but give low performance in some scenarios. ( I didn't test my demo with flann )

So my question is: For a very very very large database of descriptors which matcher should I use to get good results?

If you suggest brute force matcher, is there a way I could make it even more faster? (multi threading etc.)

If you suggest flann, is there a way to make it more accurate? (and keep the speed)?

Comment: for a large descriptor list, flann is your best bet. Brute force will compare every descriptor pair and take a long time in a "very very very large" descriptor set. Unless your features are binary descriptors (require hamming dist rather than euclidean/mahalanobis) and thus need bfmatcher in opencv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BruteForceMatcher is a greedy matcher, which compares each pair of descriptors, so FlannMatcher should be faster on large databases. On the other hand, if you use special metrics, you need to use BruteForceMatcher

Comment: thank you MisteryGuy. I've been waiting 3 years for an answer :)

Comment: what would be the order of magnitude of a database in order to be considered large?